# How is syntax used in a program?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I have used the `program` command in Stata quite a few times now.

Today, I am trying to teach myself how to create a program that uses input. I've tried looking at the `syntax` help file and at page 71 of [these lecture slides I found on the internet](http://resep.sun.ac.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Basic-Stata-Programming.pdf), but I can't figure out how to do this.

I would appreciate it if you could show me some documentation that covers this specific topic thoroughly. Or just point out what I'm doing wrong below.

As you can see, all I want is to create a short program that checks whether a file exists in the specified folder (`capture confirm file`), but I want to display my own dialogue box if there is an error (`window stopbox note`) and if so, then exit the `do` file in an orderly manner (`exit 601`).

```
cap program drop checkfile
program checkfile
syntax varlist, folder(varname) file(varname)
capture confirm file "`folder'/`file'"
    if _rc == 601 {
        window stopbox note `"`file' is not in `folder'"' // creates a dialogue box for the error
        exit 601
    }
end

checkfile folder(C:\Users\User\Documents) file(NIDSw5.dta)
```

Returns the error:

> factor-variable and time-series operators not allowed
>   r(101);

I'm not sure how to use `syntax` in order to get the folder path and file name. Note that these are usually strings, but I'm guessing that:

```
"`folder'/`file'"
```

will result in, for example, `""C:\Users\User\Documents"/"NIDSw5.dta""` if the input is done with quotation marks, so that's why I thought I should use the `local(input)` method.

Also note that I will use a global variable (`$DataIN`) instead of putting the folder path string there, and the file name contains a global variable appended onto a string.

Removing `varlist,` results in the error:

> invalid syntax
>   r(197);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
program checkfile
syntax, folder(string) file(string)
capture confirm file "`folder'/`file'"
if _rc == 601 {
    window stopbox note `"`file' is not in `folder'"' 
    exit 601
}
end
```

You then simply need to type:

```
checkfile, folder(C:\Users\User\Documents) file(NIDSw5.dta)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also do it without using options as follows:

```
program checkfile
capture confirm file "`1'/`2'"
if _rc == 601 {
    window stopbox note `"`2' is not in `1'"'
    exit 601
}
end

checkfile C:\Users\User\Documents NIDSw5.dta
```